# Какая сложность у подобного алгоритма?

Tags: python, алгоритм

Правильно ли я понимаю, что:

```
for i in range(len(abc)):
    if i in zxc:
```

по сути имеет сложность O(n^2) так как мы имеем цикл сложностью O(n) и внутри него используем in, который так же имеет сложность O(n)?

Comment: Это правда если `zxc` список, кортеж или дек. Это не правда если `xzc` множество, например.

Comment: Рассуждая  только про *n* вы предполагаете что длины `abc` и `zxc` (если он список) сравнимы. Это действительно так?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Цикл `for i in range(len(abc))` имеет сложность **O(n)**, **n** - длина списка **abc**.

Операция `if i in zxc`, имеет сложность **O(m)**, где **m** - длина списка **zxc**.

Общая сложность будет **O(n * m)**.